# Spring declare multiple beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have an HashMap of myobjects which I want to loop through and declare each one of them as bean.  At the end I want to choose one particular key as @primary.

Is there anyway to do this in Spring Java Config?

I can't really do this in listeners as these beans are required when context loads up.  I was looking at factory beans but could not figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of beans by getting a reference to [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) in one of your Java configuration classes. For example,

```
@Configuration
public class ServicesConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void onPostConstruct() {
       Map<String, MyClass> mapOfClasses = HashMap<>(); // your HashMap of objects
       AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
       BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) autowireCapableBeanFactory;

       for (Map.Entry<String, MyClass> myClassEntry : mapOfClasses.entrySet()) {
         GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
         beanDefinition.setBeanClass(myClassEntry.getValue().getClass());
         beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
         registry.registerBeanDefinition(myClassEntry.getKey(), beanDefinition);
         autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(myClassEntry,
                AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, false);
       }
    }
}
```

Here `MyClass` is the type of your `myobject` and each `MyClass` can also have [@Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotations. At this point, I assume that each of these objects will be given their bean name the key of the `HashMap`. This objects then can be used as dependencies for other beans if you want.

Same thing can be achieved by implementing [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) and overriding [postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html#postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry-org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry-) to register your `HashMap` of objects. In this method you will be able to create [BeanDefinition](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html)s with [BeanDefinitionBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.html).

```
AbstractBeanDefinition beanDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(MyClass.class).getBeanDefinition();
beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("key_of_this_object", beanDefinition);
```

I'm not sure if you can mark one of these beans as @Primary. But based on this [post](http://develop.nydi.ch/2010/12/30/spring-primary-bean-injection/) you can define your own bean resolver by extending [DefaultListableBeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html) which I haven't tested myself. As an alternative you may use [@Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) as you already know which object is going to be the primary bean.

Hope this will help.

P.S If objects are already available to be added in to the [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html), following approach would add these custom objects to ApplicationContext

```
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).getBeanFactory();
configurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("key_of_this_object", myClassObject);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works when I have a list of Class<T> in HashMap.  My requirement was slightly different in the sense I already had myClass instances in HashMap which I want to register as singleton.  I ended up implementing ApplicationContextAware to get ApplicationContext and then registering instances.  Thanks for your help.